Including option in a package
I want to include the following as an option to a package.Have included the keys part.  What more needs be done ?
\RequirePackage {multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}

in
\ProvidesPackage{rodin}[2024 Package]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l_rodin_col_bool

\keys_define:nn { rodin_keys }
  {
    col .bool_set:N = \l_rodin_col_bool,
    col .initial:n = false,
    col .default:n = true,
    col .value_required:n = false,
    col .usage = general,

  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[col]{rodin}

\begin {document}


\end {document}


Welcome! What are you trying to do exactly? To make col a package option you need to process your package's keys e.g. \ProcessKeyOptions [ rodin_keys ] but it is not obvious what the connection is between this and the first snippet you give where you load multicol.

I want to make col a package option.  When activated \RequirePackage {multicol}  \setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm} will take effect.

\ProvidesPackage{rodin}[2024 Package] is an error. if you use the optional argument the first word must be a yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd date.

To use the keys as package options, you need to process them. For example,
\keys_define:nn { rodin_keys }
  {
    col .bool_set:N = \l_rodin_col_bool,
    col .initial:n = false,
    col .default:n = true,
    col .value_required:n = false,
    col .usage = general,

  }

\ProcessKeyOptions [ rodin_keys ]

\ExplSyntaxOff

To make something actually depend on the boolean, you need to wrap it in a conditional which tests whether the boolean is true or false. For example,
\bool_if:NT \l_rodin_col_bool
{
  \RequirePackage {multicol}
  \setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}
}

But, in that case, you shouldn't mark the key for general use. It should either be preamble or load because you can't load multicol after \begin{document}.

I shall change it to preamble.  Is this all that has to be done ?

Could I just include your \l_rodin_col_bool condition just after \ProcessKeyOptions [ rodin_keys ] ?

@Franklin If you restrict usage to load, sure.
